# Mongorestore to AWS EC2

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mongorestore

I just made a migration from a linode server to amazon EC2. For my linode, I was able to restore my database image using the following syntax:

./mongorestore -h *[IP of server]* -d *[databaseName]* -u *[username]* -p *[password]* *[local directory of backup image]*

However, following this syntax using AWS EC2 doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions as to what to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context as to what the actual error(s) is/are that you are getting?  Are you attempting to run mongorestore from the directory where it's installed as your pasted command above indicates?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what error you're getting, but it might be the syntax that's causing the issue. The example in the docs doesn't have the `./` in front of `mongorestore`. So your command should look like this:

```
mongorestore -h [IP of server] -d [databaseName] -u [username] -p [password] [local directory of backup image]
```

Docs for v4.4:
https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongorestore/